# How can we initiate more than 6 HTTP connections with web worker in Angular14?

Tags: file-upload, web-worker, httpconnection, angular14

I am using web worker to upload files parallelly.
Once the user uploads files I am iterating over the for loop and create a worker for each file. I am not facing issues while creating multiple workers.

But when I upload say 25 files then 25 workers get created. The API call inside each worker is the pain point

The first 6 HTTP API calls are getting triggered parallelly and the rest are waiting to complete the previous one.

That means only 6 parallel HTTP connections are getting generated.

How can I open more than 6 http connections at the same time?